# How to listen for observable without getting Recursion error

Tags: angular, recursion

My Angular app has an Angular FormControl that consists of 2 radio buttons.

I want to set a boolean based on the selected value (i.e. which radio button the user selects).

Here is my Form:

```
<form [formGroup]="roleForm">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="role">Role:</label>
        <label class="radio-inline">
        <input type="radio" value="employee" formControlName="role">Employee
        </label>
        <label class="radio-inline">
        <input type="radio" value="manager" formControlName="role">Manager
        </label>
    </div>
</form>
```

Here is my Typescript:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.roleForm = this.fb.group({
        role: ['employee']
    });

    this.roleForm.get('role').valueChanges.subscribe((role: string) => {
        this.onRoleChange(role);
    });
}

onRoleChange(role: string) {
    if (role === 'employee') {
        this.rdoEmployeeSelected = true;
        console.log('ROLE: ' + role);
        this.onRoleChange(role);
    } else {
        this.rdoEmployeeSelected = false;
        console.log('ROLE: ' + role);
    }
}
```

When I compile the project, I get no errors, & `employee` is selected by default. Also, when I choose `Manager`, it is logged to the console fine.

But, if I re-select `employee`,  employee is logged to the console a few thousand times & I eventually get the following error:

> InternalError: too much recursion

Can someone please tell me how I can update my `rdoEmployeeSelected` boolean based on which radio button is selected, without crashing the app?

Comment: Why do you have `this.onRoleChange(role)` under `onRoleChange(){}`?

Comment: @xyz Hi, Typo! That was the problem! Working fine now when that's removed